# Same Block Received More Than Once With Same Block Parameters

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, infura, blocks

**Use Case:**
I am implementing a deposit system where I will get a block as it is mined and parse transactions to check for a deposit of Ether or a specific token. Getting the same block twice will result in same transactions parsed twice and that eventually might result in wrong credits etc.

To listen to blocks, I have implemented two scenarios but facing the same issue in both of them.

**Scenario 1:**
web3 version 0.19.0
Node Version 8.12.0
Ethereum Node: Geth Rinkeby Node Running on AWS

I use web3.eth.filter to listen to the latest block hashes and print the latest block info. For some blocks, I get the same block number twice.

```
var filter = web3.eth.filter('latest');
filter.watch(function(error, result) {
  if (!error) {
    web3.eth.getBlock(result, true, function(error, data) {
      if(!error)
      {
        console.log('Block: '+data.number+' Transactions Count: ',data.transactions.length);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

**Output:**

```
/* Notice the Block Number 3205025 Fired Twice with the same txn count */
Block:  3205023 Transactions: 39
Block:  3205024 Transactions: 24
Block:  3205024 Transactions: 24
Block:  3205025 Transactions: 17
```

**Scenario 2:**
web3 version 1.0.0 beta 36
Node Version 8.12.0
Ethereum Node Node: Infura Rinkeby Websocket

I used web3.eth.subscribe to subscribe to latest block headers and as a result, I get exactly same block headers emitted more than once from the emitter.

```
const Web3 = require('web3');
const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.WebsocketProvider('wss://rinkeby.infura.io/ws'))

const subscription = web3.eth.subscribe('newBlockHeaders');

subscription.subscribe((error, result) => {
  if (error) console.log(error)
})
.on('data', async (block) => {
  console.log(block.number);
});
```

**Output:**

```
3215743
3215743
3215744
3215744
3215744
3215744
```

Am I doing anything wrong or is it the usual behavior or is there any way to handle the duplication of the exact same block.

Comment: Try printing the block hashes, you are likely receiving minor forks.

Comment: I printed the block hashes. Hashes are same, so are the block numbers, but it syncs on my node twice. Are they uncles?

Comment: maybe this would help https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/66423/why-is-geth-importing-the-same-block-multiple-times